# How to access data inside ViewBag in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

Hi can someone tell how to access data inside of ViewBag in Asp.net. I will explain better for what. I have a projet that the users can post something, and each user have name surname and image. Then after the user posts should apear the what the wrote and is name surname and his photo.
For now i have this code on the controller:

```
var posts_public = from p in db.Posts
                               join e in db.Privacy on p.id_post equals e.id_post
                               join pu in db.Publish on p.id_post equals pu.id_post
                               join u in db.Users on pu.id_user equals u.id_user
                               where e.id_privacy== 1
                               select new { p.text, u.name, u.surname, u.image};

            ViewBag.Posts = posts_public;
```

And on the view i have this:

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Posts)
        {
            @item

        }
```

But the result i get is

```
{text = hello, name = Pedro, Surname = Filipe, image = \Content\Imgs\Img4}
```

What i want to achieve is something like this:

```
(image of user) img src="\Content\Imgs\Img4) Pedro Filipe 
Hello
```

But i can't separate that data inside of viewbag. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is how you do it in razor syntax.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Posts)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@item.image">
        <p class="name">@item.name @item.Surname</p>
        <p class="message">@item.text</p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: i get this error :An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'image' :/

Comment: the object you have added in the Viewbag probably does not have the image property. You might want to debug the list and get the exact property name.

Comment: but evern with the item.name is gettting me same error : Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for name :/